# SoundManager.setup not running on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, soundmanager2

We have a web app that works fine on both PC (Windows, Linux, OSX) and Android but is not working on IOS. After lots of debugging, we've narrowed the cause down to the `soundManager.setup` function.

```
soundManager.setup({
    onready: function () {
        startGame();
    }
});
```

There a no console error messages, on IOS the startGame(); command just won't run (and our web app will keep loading). 
If I move the `startGame()` command out of the function like so:

```
startGame();
soundManager.setup({
    onready: function () {
        startGame();
    }
});
```

The game starts, but no sound is played.

Its an older codebase and I have very little experience with soundManager, so I was wondering if anyone here had run here into similar problems - and if so - how they managed to solve it.